# Ruby methods without class?

Tags: ruby

Hey everyone!  I was wondering how the methods in Ruby that aren't called with the syntax `ClassName.method_name` work.  Some off the top of my head are `puts`, `print`, `gets`, `chomp`.  These methods can be called without using the dot operator.  Why is this?  Where do they come from?  And how can I see the full list of such methods?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All methods in `Kernel` will be available to all objects of class `Object` or any class derived from `Object`. You can use `Kernel.instance_methods` to list them.

Comment: Not exactly right, as they will be available to objects whose class subclasses `Obejct`. Instances of classes based off `BasicObject` will not have `Kernel` methods.

Comment: Cool. I took the liberty of removing `Kernel.methods` from your answer, as it would also include `Kernel` singleton methods, if any, that are not included in `Object` (e.g. `def Kernel.foo; end`)

Answer (score 1):

They come from the `Kernel` module that is automatically included for each class. Those

```
irb(main):001:0> class Foo
irb(main):002:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> Foo.included_modules
=> [Kernel]
```

Comment: Even shorter: `Class.new.included_modules`. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but "automatically included" can be misleading, and is not quite right... Misleading because it sounds like an action of including `Kernel` is done by Ruby, but it's simply because new classes have `Object` as an ancestor, and `Object` includes `Kernel`. Include any other module in `Object` and you will get the same effect; there is nothing special about `Kernel`. It's not quite right because classes subclassed from `BasicObject` will not have `Kernel` included.